# evaluation or simplification of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

i need a help to evaluate or simplify as possible the following integrals , my aim is find an approximation to this integration :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBC9w.jpg)

$$m(x)=\int_0^x \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}\exp\left(-\frac 1 {2bx}\left(\frac t x +\frac x t -2\right)\right) dt$$

Comment: Welcome on Math.se ! Here You first should show your work (what have you done). Secondly, try to use $\LaTeX$ to write down math formulas.

Comment: in which limt you want to approximate?